# AWS Redshift vacuum returns ERROR: Assert

Tags: amazon-redshift, vacuum

Trying to vacuum a table in our Redshift cluster returns:

Error : ERROR:  Assert

For other tables vacuum works just fine. The table is fairly large, but queries run against it seem to work.

Any idea how to get more info on what's wrong and trying to fix? Should I try making a copy of the table (probably an overnight job, given the table size)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Probably if you update your cluster it will fix the issue.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=245468